# Sphinxtrain senone.c error and pocketsphinx_continuous bin_mdef.c error

Tags: speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

As I'm building a sinhala speech recognition system using pocketsphinx I have come across two major error while running **sphinxtrain run** command and  **pocketsphinx_continuous** command my project folder can be seen [HERE](http://www.megafileupload.com/hs3X/sinhala.rar). Still I'm using small data set and currently I'm in the process of recording some more words. After running sphinxtrain run command I have copied following files to pocketsphinx language model default location **/usr/local/share/pocketsphinx/model/en-us/** by creating a folder call **si**,

- mdef
- feat.params
- mixture_weights
- means
- noisedict
- transition_matrices
- variances
- sinhala.dic
- sinhala.lm
- sinhala.phone

Then I ran **pocketsphinx_continuous** command and the Errors I got are [HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=79538186327087788702).

1. For sinhala language It is very dificult to redice number of phones specially below 255. Is their any solution for that?
2. Why I'm getting senone.c error mentioned in the logs? and How to correct it?
3. Does SRILM support to create .lm.bin files for sinhala language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> sphinxtrain run command and pocketsphinx_continuous command my project folder can be seen HERE.

It is better to use more user-friendly websites for sharing like google drive or dropbox. It is not polite to ask people to use websites with spam and adware.

> For sinhala language It is very dificult to redice number of phones specially below 255. Is their any solution for that?

Use smaller phoneset. According to the paper

http://www.panl10n.net/english/final%20reports/pdf%20files/Sri%20Lanka/SRI04.pdf

you can use just 40 phonemes

> Why I'm getting senone.c error mentioned in the logs? and How to correct it?

You are using too many phonemes, use smaller phonemes

> Does SRILM support to create .lm.bin files for sinhala language?

No, you can use LM created with SRILM directly without conversion to lm.bin

Comment: I'm extremely sorry about the spam and adware website. In future I will upload to dropbox or google drive.

Comment: Now i reduce my phone set to only 51 but I'm still getting following error once I ran **sphinxtrain run** command:=  `ERROR: FATAL: "senone.c", line 213: fopen(/home/anuradha/Desktop/Workspace/sinhala/model_parameters/sinhala.cd_semi_200_delinterp/mixture_weights,rb) failed`

Comment: Here is my project files now in Google drive [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-TSEc3hQdkmYlVFYUZwQlJJWEU/view?usp=sharing) **Can I use sentences in Transcription file?** I tried that and got some errors saying words in the transcription file not available in .dic file. But I have included the words into .dic file.**Then Why I got those errors?** I only use words to build my Language and Acoustic models so far. **Is it the best way or should I use sentences also mix with words in language and acoustic models?**